# Plotly: How to use the same color scheme on two subplots?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to plot two scatter subplots with plotly whereby the colour automatically chosen in the two sub-plots is the same, but I cannot find a way to do so.

Following is a code snippet:

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.tools as to
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
fig=to.make_subplots(rows=1,cols=2,subplot_titles=['Plot 1','Plot 2'])
X=[0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500]
Y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
Z=Y.copy()
for i  in np.arange(11):
    if i==0:
            Z[0]=Y[0]
    else:
            Z[i]=Y[i]+Z[i-1]
trace=go.Scatter(x=X,y=Y)
fig.append_trace(trace,1,1)
trace=go.Scatter(x=X,y=Z,showlegend=False)
fig.append_trace(trace,1,2);
py.offline.plot(fig)
```

The above code plots two subplots and the scatters will have a different colour. I want them to have the same colour. I am aware that I can hard-code the colour on the two scatters but I need the colours to be selected automatically from some colour scheme.

[image]

How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you

Comment: @vestland I just had to something similar and this worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

The following suggestion uses plotly version `4.2.0`, but the approach regarding the colors should be the same.

You can set the color of your lines in markers in your subplots using:

```
line=dict(width=2, color=cols[0])
marker=dict(color=cols[1])
```

If you'd like to work with a certain color scheme you can pick up the default plotly colors using:

```
#in:
import plotly
cols = plotly.colors.DEFAULT_PLOTLY_COLORS

#out:
['rgb(31, 119, 180)',
 'rgb(255, 127, 14)',
 'rgb(44, 160, 44)',
 'rgb(214, 39, 40)',
 'rgb(148, 103, 189)',
 'rgb(140, 86, 75)',
 'rgb(227, 119, 194)',
 'rgb(127, 127, 127)',
 'rgb(188, 189, 34)',
 'rgb(23, 190, 207)']
```

Here's an example that uses the same colors from the same color scheme on the lines, and a bit different colors on the markers.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
# imports
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly

cols = plotly.colors.DEFAULT_PLOTLY_COLORS


fig=make_subplots(rows=1,cols=2,subplot_titles=['Plot 1','Plot 2'])
X=[0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500]
Y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
Z=Y.copy()
for i  in np.arange(11):
    if i==0:
            Z[0]=Y[0]
    else:
            Z[i]=Y[i]+Z[i-1]
trace=go.Scatter(x=X,
                 y=Y,
                 line=dict(width=2, color=cols[0]),
                 marker=dict(color=cols[1]),
                 showlegend=False
                )
fig.append_trace(trace,1,1)

trace=go.Scatter(x=X,
                 y=Z,
                 line=dict(width=2, color=cols[0]),
                 marker=dict(color=cols[7]),
                 showlegend=False)

fig.append_trace(trace,1,2)

fig.show()
```