# Legend sharing Plotly Dash Legendgroup

Tags: python, plotly-dash, legend-properties

I am working with multiple plots in my dashboard, all have same time on x axis, same multiple traces (dates) and different values on yaxis.

I want to click on a chart legend and all other charts should do the same. I tried subplots, worked but colors are allways different and also some other issues. Any idea if this is possible without using subplots or a keyword that i have missed?

Thank you very much

Comment: I think subplots with shared x axes is the only way here. The colors can be fixed with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549054/plotly-how-to-use-the-same-color-scheme-on-two-subplots. What are the other issues that you are experiencing?

Comment: i can use subplots, but i need a legend next to each chart. If i use subplots my legens are doubled or i set them false and one only true, then i have a legend next to the right upper chart but not one legend for one graph.

Comment: What if you do this programmatically? So you create multiple graphs and then have a callback on each one on the attribute "relayoutData". Whenever the x-range is changed on one graph a callback is called from which you can then set the x-range of all the other graphs accordingly. See this page for more information on relayoutData callbacks: https://dash.plot.ly/interactive-graphing.

Comment: yes this could work, thank you...